# Regular expression to extract text between two sets of characters (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to extract some text between two points in a string, in Javascript

Say the string is

```
"start-extractThis-234"
```

The numbers at the end can be any number, but the hyphens are always present.

Ideally I think capturing between the two hypens should be ok.

I would like the result of the regex to be

```
extractThis
```

Comment: Wow, I wonder how many of my old questions I'll be embarrised about like this one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not just do

```
var toExtract = "start-extractThis-234";
var extracted = null;
var split = toExtract.split("-");
if(split.length === 3){
   extracted = split[1];
}
```

Comment: +1 for this.  As long as the string format will always be like this then `split` is a much better choice than a regex match.  `if` statement might be a bit overkill though, `extracted = split[1];` or `if (extracted = split[1])` should be enough for most situations.

Comment: yeah the if is a bit overkill, i wanted to be verbose

Comment: Accepted due to simplicity, I was hoping to learn a bit of funky Regex but I can't turn down readability. I shouldn't have been making this complicated!

Comment: @optician: don't worry, you'll get your chance at learning some funky regex sooner or later ;-)

Answer (score 4):

```
string = "start-extractThis-234"

console.log( string.match( '-(.*)-' )[1] );

//returns extractThis
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^.+?-(.+?)-\d+$
```

Comment: I will asses if this works, and if so vote it up, as it is the correct answer! I was hoping to be able to choose the split points, so this may be helpful.

Comment: I like this solution better than the other one. But all this is is a regular expression. but which javascript method you use to extract between the two characters?